# SharePoint 2016 - Slow response for any thing on settings page and load time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am seeing a strange behavior in a new SharePoint 2016 farm and will appreciate any input advice on this or if someone can confirm its a bug or something else.

Environment:

1WFE server: (WFE with DC MinRole)

1APP server: (Application MinRole)

1 Search Server: (Search MinRole).

Everything is functional including UPS, Search, Metadata and other service application. Wake up script is implemented.

Observation: (complex but I will try to explain)

After creating a new web application and site collection, it takes a long time to load (more than 5 min sometimes). but once it’s loaded it will be faster next time.

Now after IIS reset and execution of a wake-up script, if I click on Add new page or New list, or new item within the list, its taking long time to load the first time. if I do the same within few minutes it's faster. it seems like something is blocking any action for the first time.

if I don't use a system for some time (for few hours may be) and load site again, I see the same slow response again for a home page to load. 
After accessing site few times and making sure site is coming in 2 seconds I went to site settings page and start clicking on few option like search settings / Results source /Term Store management or any link on settings page to see response for each it takes noticeably long time (more than 45 seconds in most cases) which is not normal. any idea where to look at or is it a known thing with MinRole?

Some findings:
I have check Distributed cache and find not issue in ULS, connectivity between servers and DB goes up to <6ms once a while. 
ULS don't return too many things when a search for execution time > 3 seconds. 
All these tests are on OOB site, no customizations yet. 
Any thoughts, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is JIT lag and is perfectly normal. The Application Pools will need to spin up, compiling (Just-in-Time) the binaries needed to support what you're doing. As the primary binary, Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is quite large, this can take some time, not to mention the other binaries in use. Application Pools need to spin up after server restarts, iisreset, or if they shutdown due to idle timeout.

If you have a warmup script, it sounds like it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for response , I have other environments ( 2013 ) as well and have not seen any thing line this. I have also tested the same in 2016 single server farm , no issues there.    If this is normal after IISReset why do I see the same behavior 4 hours after site is working fine. A simple scenario is I click on new item in list and took several minutes for form to load for new item. when home page was loading in 2 seconds. when calling for newitem.aspx server is not even going to DB server. -- I double checked script in other  environment and it is fine there. Any other thoughts ?